# How to designate a route interface without gateway in FreeBSD?

Tags: linux, networking, freebsd

Due to I only want to designate a route interface without gateway, in linux system, I could use ip command like as `ip route add default dev eth0`. But in FreeBSD, there is no ip command. What should I do?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

As you can read from bsd [handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-routing.html) you can use the route command
Type

```
route add default eth0
```

Comment: Thank you. I have attempt to use route command, but it prompt `route: bad address: eth0`. This FreeBSD is a customized system and the host is Google Cloud. I guess it might cause some effect.

Comment: You should write the name of your network interface instead of `eth0`.